# is Luis include extra cost for sentiment analysis or bing spell check?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have Luis api service and if i enable spell check and sentiment analysis in Luis. do i need to pay extra money for luis or azure will be created different cognitive service and use it in luis.

Answer (score 0):

Sentiment Analysis is available at no additional cost. You just need to turn it on from the Publish settings in luis.ai portal.

I do not know why there is a selection for Bing Spell Check there too because it doesn't work. If you are using LUIS v2 `LuisRecognizer`, you can set this up directly in your recognizer definition. You do need to have a separate Bing resource created. You can either use the Bing Spell Check (which has a free tier as well as paid tiers) or Bing Search (which is paid only). Bing search provides more services, and depending on your expected usage, may actually be more cost effective at certain transaction volumes. Note that if you use the free tier, you have a hard limit on transactions per month. Here is how you add Bing Spell Check to your recognizer:

```js
const myRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer({
            applicationId: process.env.LuisAppId,
            endpointKey: process.env.LuisAPIKey,
            endpoint: `https://${ process.env.LuisAPIHostName }`
        }, {
            includeAllIntents: true,
            includeInstanceData: true,
            spellCheck: true,
            bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey: process.env.bingAPIKey
        }, true);
```

Note that in the latest LUIS version, there is no option to set up spell check directly. You will need to send your utterance directly to the spell check service first, and then send that modified utterance to LUIS. I like doing it this older way, but for new development you might as well start out with the new version.

Here are some resources for pricing:

- [Bing Spell Check Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/spellcheck-api/)
- [Text Analytics Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/text-analytics/) (not needed for LUIS endpoint, included for reference)

Comment: is there any microsoft documents where i can find these details as we need to give price estimation for client.

Comment: Generally if you Google `Azure SERVICE_NAME pricing` you'll get an answer right on the results page, and if not there is usually a pricing page link in the top 3 results. I have added pricing links to the answer.